# How do I make my flask wtforms SelectField look like a dropdown?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I've created a SelectField like so:

```
class Inputs(Form):
    myChoices = #number of choices
    myField = SelectField(u'Field name', choices = myChoices, validators = [Required()])
```

The problem is that when it renders in my template:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="Inputs">
    {{form.hidden_tag()}}
    <p>
        {{form.myField(size=80)}}
    </p>
</form>
```

It looks like a long select box with all the values already shown, rather than a drop-down menu. How do I change this formatting? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem was the `(size=80)` in my html - I deleted this and it works fine. I thought this was a way to limit the size of the dropdown similar to TextField form field, but obviously not!

Comment: Did you find out how to limit the size after all?

Comment: you do that using CSS

Comment: `(size="x")` where `x`being the number of items you want to show